# ruby non-blocking line read

Tags: ruby, io, nonblocking

I'm trying to read a line from an io in a non-blocking way.

Unfortunately `readline` blocks. I think I can solve this with `read_nonblock` with an additional buffer where I store partial result, check if there are multiple lines in the buffer, etc.. but it seems a bit complicated for a simple task like this. Is there a better way to do this?

Note: I'm using event demultiplexing (`select`) and I'm quite happy with it, I don't want to create threads, use EventMachine, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the read_nonblock solution is probably the way to go.  Simple, not maximally efficient monkey-patch version:

```
class IO
  def readline_nonblock
    rlnb_buffer = ""
    while ch = self.read_nonblock(1) 
      rlnb_buffer << ch
      if ch == "\n" then
        result = rlnb_buffer
        return result
      end
    end     
  end
end
```

That throws an exception if there's no data ready, just like read_nonblock, so you have to rescue that to just get a nil back, etc.

Comment: Yeah, that was my original idea, and that's what I finally did, but I read as much as I can (not just a single char), I think that's better for performance. Thanks for the monke-patch tip ;)

Answer (score 3):

This implementation improves on Mark Reed's answer by not discarding data read that does not end in a newline:

```
class IO
  def readline_nonblock
    buffer = ""
    buffer << read_nonblock(1) while buffer[-1] != "\n"

    buffer
  rescue IO::WaitReadable => blocking
    raise blocking if buffer.empty?

    buffer
  end
end
```

Comment: "no guarantee" - that's kinda scary. don't rely on undocumenteded 'features'. "I tested this" - thorougly? with different input methods? It may only worked because your input was line buffered...

Comment: I wasn't brave enough to rely on it either, which is why I included the second part. :-)

Comment: I verified that `read_nonblock(4096)` does not return a single line on ruby 1.9.3, 2.0.0, and 2.1.3.  Better take this suggestion out. Easy enough to verify with `ruby19 -e 'x = IO.popen("cat /etc/fstab"); sleep 0.2; p x.read_nonblock(4096)'`.

Comment: Thank you. Editing out that "no guarantee" suggestion.

Comment: So what about encoding? If the buffered input ends in the middle of a multi-byte character sequence, and then Ruby transcodes during reading, and then we concatenate another transcoded block that starts in the middle of a multi-byte character sequence, what happens? Does Ruby IO prevent that by internally buffering the partial last character in the external encoding and then prepend it to the next chunk? I can't find anything in the Ruby docs that talks about that.

Comment: Tried an experment. Given a foo.txt file containing "123456789Ž12345678", … `2.2.2 :001 > io = File.open('foo.txt','r') // => #<File:foo.txt> // 2.2.2 :002 > a=io.readpartial(10) // => "123456789\xC5" // 2.2.2 :003 > b=io.readpartial(10) // => "\xBD12345678\n" // 2.2.2 :004 > a+b // => "123456789\xC5\xBD12345678\n"`